# HTML form refreshes on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a javascript function that submits a form. I have searched through a lot of questions and found answers, but that does not seem to help.

```
function setActionAndSubmit(action){
    $('input:hidden[name=action]').val(action);
    $("blueForm").submit();
}
```

I have seen some answers where people suggested
         `return false;`
But that does not seem to work either.

How do I stop the submit from refreshing the page?

Comment: Submitting a form loads a new page. If you don't want to reload the page, you should use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's ajax helpers to submit it instead. The below code will make the same request as submitting a form, except doesn't redirect/refresh the page. `callback` is called with the response.

```
function setActionAndSubmit(action, callback) {
  var $form = $("blueForm");
  $form.find('input:hidden[name=action]').val(action);
  $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), callback);
}
```